# How to active a tab in kendo ui angular 2 programmatically

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

Kendo UI angular 2 TabStripComponent has a method selectTab. How can I use it to active a tab from the typescript code?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the selectTab(index) method from the tabstrip component.

First, add a selector to your tabstrip in your view component:

```
<kendo-tabstrip #tabstrip>... </kendo-tabstrip>
```

Now, you can access the tabstrip from your module via

```
@ViewChild('tabstrip') public tabstrip: TabStripComponent;
```

Finally, you can activate any tab using its index with

```
tabstrip.selectTab(index);
```

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xoEQX58azm0AMDke3lL8?p=preview) if you want to have a look.

Be aware that it will not switch if the targeted tab is disabled!

Comment: works well but wont work in ngOnInit as the tabs have to render first before you can reference them.

Comment: @Bhail You're right. ngAfterViewInit is where tab selects work as the component gets created

Answer (score 0):

can't realy find how to use `selectTab` Method but you can use the `selected` property to decide which tab is active. As shown in the [documentation](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/layout/tabstrip/configuration/)

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
[selected]="i == selected"
```

or

```
selected value = true from ts end
```

then what u want that tab will be actvie

```
ex:selected=0;
```

first tab will be active